# Mongo, counting items in arrays in several documents via Lookup

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

We have a collection with documents called **notes** like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64b42008f622157dd5aead17"
  },
  "isbn": 9789401466097,
  "chapter": 2,
  "notes": [
    {
      "note": "a note",
      "dt": 2374238742345,
    },
    {
      "note": "another note about the same book and chapter",
      "dt": 2345234234,
    }
  ]
}
```

and a second similar document (and more)

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64b42234f622157dd5aead1c"
  },
  "isbn": 9789401466097,
  "chapter": 1,
  "notes": [
    {
      "note": "A note about the same book but another chapter",
      "dt": 23742387423
    },
  ]
}

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64b42234f6223de7dd5aead1c"
  },
  "isbn": 9789401488088,
  "chapter": 1,
  "notes": [
    {
      "note": "something about another book",
      "dt": 23742384555
    },
    {
      "note": "something else",
      "dt": 23452333333
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Other similar documents may have the same or other **isbs** or other **chapters**.

The combination of **isbn** and **chapter** form the unique key for a document.

Then there's the collection of **books** (hence the isbn). So with:

```
collection = 'books' # using pythons pymongo
match = {'$match': {'isbn': isbn}}
projection = {'$project':
        {
            '_id': '$_id',
            'isbn': '$isbn',
            'title': '$title',
        }
    }

pipeline = [
        {'$facet':
            {
                'the_book':
                    [
                        match,
                        projection,
                    ],
            }
        }
    ]
```

I consult and project the collection of **books**.

What I try to accomplish is to count all of the notes that are made for all of the chapters for the book with a given **isbn**.

What I've tried:

```
lookup_notes = {'$lookup':
        {
            'from': 'notes',
            'localField': 'isbn',
            'foreignField': 'isbn',
            'as': 'note',
        },
    }
project_notes = {'$project':
        {
            "teller": {
                "$size": '$note.notes'
            }
        }
    }
pipeline = [
        {'$facet':
            {
                'the_book':
                    [
                        match,
                        projection,
                    ],
                'the_notes':
                    [
                        lookup_notes,
                        match,
                        project_notes,
                    ],
            }
        }
    ]
```

as well as a lot of other attempts using $group, $size and $count. They result in errors or only counting the amount of relevant documents in de **notes** collection, but not the combined amount of notes inside all of the relevant documents.

For the above example, with isbn=9789401466097 I should get the result 3. Not 2 or 5.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isbn = 9789401466097
match = {"$match": {"isbn": isbn}}

# join 'notes' collection.
lookup_notes = {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "notes",
        "localField": "isbn",
        "foreignField": "isbn",
        "as": "related_notes",
    },
}
# deconstruct the notes array.
unwind_notes = {
    "$unwind": "$related_notes"
}
# deconstruct the notes inside the related_notes.
unwind_inner_notes = {
    "$unwind": "$related_notes.notes"
}
# count the notes.
group_notes = {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$isbn",
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    },
}
pipeline = [match, lookup_notes, unwind_notes, unwind_inner_notes, group_notes]
result = books_collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: @Jeex does it work? Ask questions, if it's not clear, I will do my best to help you.

Comment: This solution is very inefficient, as it unwinds twice with no real reason to do so...

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

1. Start from the notes collection, as there are more documents there. Group them by `isbn` and count the notes.
2. Add the book data using `$lookup`
3. Format the result

```
db.notes.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$isbn",
      the_notes: {$sum: {$size: "$notes"}}
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "books",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "isbn",
      as: "the_book",
      pipeline: [{$project: {_id: "$_id", isbn: "$isbn", title: "$title"}}]
  }},
  {$project: {the_book: {$first: "$the_book"}, the_notes: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Jd9V-_hSlM)

Note that `$facet` is a costly option, is does not support indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both answers.

*Baktybek Baiserkeev* answer was exactly what I was looking for, *Nimrod Serok* answered implicitely another isue I was struggling with.